# Cyclic group generated by empty set.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

I have come across a problem in Durbin, Modern Algebra, that I am not quite convinced of the answer.
The question states:

> If $\emptyset$ denotes the empty set, what is $\langle\emptyset\rangle$ (in any group $G$)?

I searched for answers to this question for a while and the only one I could find stated:

> $\langle\emptyset\rangle = \{e\}$ , the identity element.

I am not quite sure of the logic behind this answer and any hints or explanations would be thoroughly appreciated.

Comment: What's the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing the empty set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*By definition*, if $S\subset G$, $\langle S\rangle$ is the smallest subgroup of $G$ which contains $S$. Since the smallest of all subgroups of $G$ is $\{e\}$ and since $\{e\}\supset\emptyset$, $\langle\emptyset\rangle=\{e\}$.

Comment: That is not always the definition; it depends on what book you're using. Some times (like in the book I used when I first learned group theory), $\langle S \rangle$ is defined as the set of all finite products of elements of $S$. This would require a different explanation (the empty product is still there, even though $S = \varnothing$).